# Will a stock 1155 cooler (i3), fit an AM2+ (Phenon X4) processor/mobo?

Tags: amd-phenom, cpu-cooler, intel-core-i3, am3, am2+

So, I want to assemble a media center and am thinking about getting a better cooler for my main computer and using that on the media center (being built with spare parts).

So, I was wondering if the stock 13-2100 cooler will fit an AM2-AM3 board, for a Phenom X4 9600. Is there any need for an adaptor, is it a straight fit or is what I'm asking plain impossible?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

The stock heatsink included with the i3-2100 is not going to fit that Phenom processor.  Your Phenom processor *should* have come with a stock heatsink.

The Phenom X4 9600 fits an [AM2+ socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socket_AM2%2B).  The i3-2100 fits an [LGA 1155 socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LGA_1155).  While you can't see it on the Wikipedia page, the LGA 1155 heatsink is held down by four pins that fit in holes in the motherboard.  The AM2+ heatsink is held down by hooks that attach to connection points on a plastic ring around the socket.  You aren't going to find the holes that the LGA 1155 heatsink needs on an AM2+ motherboard.

While there are universal heatsinks, the stock heatsink that comes with the i3 isn't one of them.  Universal heatsinks usually come with backplates and other specialized hardware to allow them to attach properly.

Comment: That's what I though. Pity. Thanks for the detailed reply!